# Crystal Reports SP26 "Database Logon failed"

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I am struggeling with a Report, which keeps asking for Database Credentials since a view days.

If I enter the Credentials which the Report is asking for, the don't work and throw an error with the message: "Database Logon Failed" - Why did the Login fail? What is wrong?

I've noticed, that the Database field is disabled and empty. For a strange reason I found out that if I install the Microsoft SSMS, I get a database name in the Database-Field.

In a previous research about that problem I read that the connection object may be missing - setting up SSMS solved the problem but that can't be the best final solution...

My guess is that there is a driver or assembly missing that SSMS includes. But which one could it be?

Current Situation:

- We were runing on SP25 since 2 Years
- We updated to SP26 at the end of 2020 -> All old Clients running fine until now
- 2 of 4 new Client Installations share this Issue -> Basic Windows 10 installation was identical

Software Type / Usage / Technology:

- We use CrystalReports for VisualStudio (CRforVS13SP26) to create the Reports
- We access the MSSQL Database as a DataSource via the OLE DB driver (DSN)
- The Report uses 4 Tables of that database and a ado.net class that we provide as a DataSource from the Code
- We pass the Login Credetials at report creation time from the Code
- The Report is Loaded on the Client Computer, not on a Report- or Webserver

What I tried:

- providing the report with credentials in different ways:
- via SetConnection(...)
- via creating a ConnectionInfo object and setting it as LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo
- installing OLE DB Driver for MSSQL Server
- installing ms sql server native client 12

Thaks in advance!

Comment: *"Why did the Login fail? What is wrong?"* we don't know, we don't have access to your instance. Check the SQL Server's logs, they will give you the *real* reason. If you then don't understand said error add that to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!


I kind of figured it out by my self.

I continued trying with different drivers because I couldn't believe that it would be the SQL-Server. In the logs I found no entries like failed login attempts from this machine.

In the End the SQL Native Client was missing on this machine, so installing SQL Native Client 12 (+ OLE DB Driver) solved the problem.